# (Veldt?) A furry species of silent, intelligent humanoids (unrelated to the Bradbury short story)

Tags: story-identification, novel, romantic-interest

I'm remembering a story of palace intrigue of I think mostly humans. One character has a companion of another species that I think were called something like Veldt(?). There is also an unrelated Bradbury short story "The Veldt" but I don't think there is any connection.

The Veldt were sentient, highly intelligent and physically fit, covered in fur, and, well... good in bed.

Their high level of perception and situational awareness made them excellent life companions, the intimacy described was only one of many examples of this in the story.

Their perceptiveness also made them good at security and excellent bodyguards.

The individual described in the story took some specific action important to the plot, but I can't remember what it was.

I'm pretty sure it was a fairly mainstream story and author.

Comment: This is ringing a faint, faint bell...do you remember anything about how the humans communicated with the companions?

Comment: @OrganicMarble no I don't. I don't recall any mention of telepathy, I think it was more like perceptiveness and good situational awareness. They somehow just knew what to do.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I found [this pdf](https://img.fireden.net/tg/image/1522/09/1522093800570.pdf) but I don't see anything in the "V" section. It is a copy of *Encyclopedia of Giants and Humanoids in Myth, Legend and Folklore* and this one doesn't seem to be text searchable unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of the age of the work?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I went on a used paperback binge roughly five years ago, so perhaps the story was published between five and twenty years ago?

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps too modern for me then.